# I need help with this LTI system-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

I dont know if I solved it correctly so far and I was wondering what I need to do to get the natural system response

$$y''+3y'-4y=x$$

[My work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQqDc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y''+3y'-4y=x$$
$$Y(s)(s^2+3s-4)=X(s)$$
For the Transfert Function, we have:
$$H(s)= \dfrac {Y(s)}{X(s)}=\dfrac 1 {s^2+3s-4}$$
$$H(s)=\dfrac 1 {(s-1)(s+4)}$$
$$5H(s)=\dfrac 1 {(s-1)}-\dfrac 1 {(s+4)}$$
For the impulse response, we have:
$$h(t)=\dfrac 1 5 \left (e^{t}-e^{-4t}\right)$$
You added an extra $s$ at the numerator. Apart from this, you applied the method correctly.